# Xamarin Android Transfer data to another app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

I have been trying to pass a parameter for quite some time while launching another app, but this fails for some inexplicable reason

Sender app:

```
public void OpenDocApp(string vorgangsnummer = null) {
        var activity = ((Activity)Forms.Context).PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("package name");
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.PutExtra("Vorgangsnummer", vorgangsnummer);
            Application.Context.StartActivity(activity);
        } else
            Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Install Second App");
    }
```

Receiver app:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        UserDialogs.Init(this);

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        var vorgangsnummer = Intent.GetStringExtra("Vorgangsnummer");
        if (vorgangsnummer != null) 
            Helpers.Tools.SetVorgangsCode(vorgangsnummer);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

The app opens but the value is not transferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem:

The problem was that the SplashScreen was started earlier than the MainActivity and therefore the result was not in the MainActivity but in the SplashScreen